# I want to select the contents,highlight it and then passing the highlighted content to other screen reacr native

Tags: react-native, text, highlight

I just want to make some app functionality using the highlighted content . i have already selected and highlighted content but way save it in use state and passing to next screen

```
const handleTextSelectionChange = (e) => {
        const { selection } = e.nativeEvent;
        if (selection) {
          const selectedPart = pageWords.substring(selection.start, selection.end);
          setSelectedText(selectedPart);
          console.log('Selected Text:', selectedPart);
        }
      };
<Text 
selectable={true} 
selectionColor='orange' 
onTextSelectionChange={handleTextSelectionChange}
            
style={{
paddingHorizontal: PAGE_MARGIN,
paddingTop: 4,
fontSize: fontSizeOfBookRead,
fontWeight: fontWeightOfBookRead,
fontFamily: "NastaliqReg"
}}>
{renderHighlightedText(pageWords, searchText)}
</Text>
```